# Display media library in a folder view in winamp 5.5

Tags: winamp

Is it possible to to display media by folders-view?
all my files organized by folders.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could find is:

http://albumlist.sourceforge.net/

> Album List turns your directory tree into a list of albums. It allows you to easily navigate your favorite albums stored on your hard drive and CDs. In addition to it being fully supported in both classic and modern skins, you also get functionalities like multiple profiles, drag & drop, global hotkeys, language packs, and more. It requires Winamp 5 and works on Windows 2K/XP.